# Como obtener un valor en python desde un json

Tags: python, json, api

estoy usando una api la cual me lee un archivo y según eso arroja unos resultados y de esos resultados yo solo necesito un valor (plate) y no he podido encontrar la forma de extraerlo

mi codigo es:

```
url = 'https://api.openalpr.com/v2/recognize_bytes?recognize_vehicle=1&country=us&secret_key=%s' % (SECRET_KEY)

r = requests.post(url, data = img_base64)

response = requests.post(url, data = img_base64)

print(response)

print(response.url)

if response.status_code == 200:

    print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2))
```

me imprime:

```
...

"results": [

 '    {

 '      "plate": "YEAUXLO",

 '      "confidence": 89.17710876464844,

 '      "region_confidence": 90,

 '      "vehicle_region": {

 '        "y": 0,

 '        "x": 134,

 '        "height": 391,

 '        "width": 391

 '      },

...
```

Comment: usa `r.json()["results"][0]["plate"]`

Comment: gracias amigo, me funcionó

Comment: `r.json()` retorna un diccionario asi que la tarea es acceder a la información del diccionario por lo que esa tarea no es complicada, te recomiendo revisar informacion acerca de diccionarios en python

Comment: si, leí información pero no di con la solución, disculpa la pregunta pero el "[0]" que significa, que pasa si pongo otro numero?

Comment: si te das cuenta en tu diccionario:  `"results": [{},  {}]`, ¿y para que se usa el simbolo []? pues para listas, asi que el valor asociado al key results es una lista¿y como accedo a un elementos de una lista? pues por el indica, en este caso use el indice 0, si la list tiene mas elementos entonces puedes usar mas indices